# Firebird update statement freezes

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

After over one day of finding & trying to solve issue its time to ask here.

We use Firebird over years (around 6) and with current version 2.5.2 updated long time ago we met the problem with unable to UPDATE statement.

SQL statement is OK, even "where" condition is used with primary key.

Problem: update is getting stuck after click on: execute
a) from PHP script it returns an Internal server error 500
b) directly from FlameRobin or IBQ it freezes and is not responding at all

1. SQL which wasn't working is working right after clean Firebird (stop & start), but after a while it gets stuck again
2. Selects are OK, problem is only with UPDATE
3. I did all described in [How To Analyse and Repair a Corrupted Database](https://www.ibphoenix.com/articles/art-00000005) (redump of database file which was giving me errors on `gfix -v -full`), after redump there were no errors, but the problem still occurs
4. We have more servers running the same configuration with more database files, but this happen only for one table in one DB file on one server.

After some investigation I finally got this from fbtrace:

```
2016-11-28T14:25:28.4410 (9473:0x7f1489cb1f08) PREPARE_STATEMENT
    phones.fdb (ATT_273856, VILAS:NONE, UTF8, TCPv4:10.1.1.195)
    /usr/bin/flamerobin:10868
        (TRA_78838, CONCURRENCY | WAIT | READ_WRITE)

Statement 422749:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE TELEFONI_CISLA SET DATUM_PRIDANI = '2011-7-3' WHERE ID = '17274'
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PLAN (TELEFONI_CISLA INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY4))
      0 ms

2016-11-28T14:25:28.4780 (9473:0x7f1489cb1f08) EXECUTE_STATEMENT_START
    phones.fdb (ATT_273856, VILAS:NONE, UTF8, TCPv4:10.1.1.195)
    /usr/bin/flamerobin:10868
        (TRA_78838, CONCURRENCY | WAIT | READ_WRITE)

Statement 422749:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE TELEFONI_CISLA SET DATUM_PRIDANI = '2011-7-3' WHERE ID = '17274'
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PLAN (TELEFONI_CISLA INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY4))
```

I'm out of ideas what to check, almost lost. Just want let you know that we didn't change anything in FB or server configuration.

Comment: Firebird 2.5.2 is not a recent version, I suggest you upgrade to at least 2.5.6. However, your problem could also be due to a lock by a concurrent transaction and your use of a `WAIT` transaction. Either use a no wait transaction, or use a wait transaction with a timeout.

Comment: EDIT: Now its running 2.5.5 and I will try to specify timeout: DeadlockTimeout to 10

Answer (score 0):

Everything was caused by one of many script running in background (from cron) taking open transaction without committing for few hours.
It's OK back again.